# How to write dataframe as a table using BasicDataSource() connection in Java?

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

In my application, I have created temporary JDBC connection from the external JAR (referenced file path) using BasicDataSource().
I can read a table using BasicDataSource(). I converted the obtained ResultSet as Dataframe from Spark API - resultSetToRows() with specific schema.
But I cannot write the dataframe as a new table into MySQL using the same connection. If anyone have suggestions, please share!

```
var urls = Array(new URL("file:///E:/mysql-connector-java-5.1.42-bin.jar"));
var urlcl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
var claz:Class[_] = Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",true,urlcl);
var driv = claz.newInstance().asInstanceOf[Driver];
DriverManager.registerDriver(driv);

var datasource = new BasicDataSource();
datasource.setUsername("username");
datasource.setPassword("xxxxxxxxxx");
datasource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
datasource.setDriverClassLoader(urlcl);
datasource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world");
```

Using the above connection `datasource` I can obtain table values as ResultSet and converted them to dataframe using Spark.
    How can I write the obtained dataframe as new table in MySQL using the above connection?

Thanks in advance!